# How to trigger esper as soon as the number of events exceed a threshold within time interval

Tags: esper

I'd like to trigger esper as soon as it receives X number of events during an interval of Y minutes. I used this query but it triggers esper only 5 minutes after having received the first event and only if it's more then 10:

```
select count(*) as total
from report.win:time_batch(5 minutes)
where type = 'test_type'
having count(*) >= 10
```

I'd like to trigger it as soon as it gets 10 messages and of course, it should evaluate an interval of 5 minutes. I do not want to trigger it if, for instance, it receives 1 event every 10 minutes. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as total
from report(type = 'test_type')#time(5 minutes)
having count(*) >= 10
```

Above query outputs a row each time count 10 or more considering 5 minutes sliding. Add for example "output first every 1 minute" if the desired output is just once every X minutes.